# how i can export excel file from cakephp or from php of databse mysql

Tags: cakephp, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, datefield

is way that i can export excel file with cakephp from database.
my data is :

```
[Name] [Tel] [Email]    [date]
Name 1  000  1@name.com (0000-00-00)
Name 2  000  2@name.com (1391-12-01)
Name 3  000  3@name.com (1391-12-01)
```

type of fields is :
Name and email is `varchar`
tel is `int`
date is `Date type`

I convert my date field in database to `locate date.( Persian date )` and if i export from data with Mysql, I can not convert date field to locate date.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out PHPExcel library at http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/. There is a CakePHP plugin for it as well.